# How would you change or rather optimize this postgres sql query so that the output format remains the same?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

Original expensive and slow query is this:

```
select 'INTEGRATED' as "STATUS", coalesce(sum(response_count),0) as "COUNT" from f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-22 00:00:00','2015-08-05 01:00:00', null, 'LINK')
where wfc_result in ('TM_OK', 'TM_NO_CHANGE')
union
select 'WFC_FALLOUT' as "STATUS", coalesce(sum(response_count),0) as "COUNT" from f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-22 00:00:00','2015-08-05 01:00:00', null, 'LINK')
where wfc_result LIKE 'WFC%'
union
select 'TM_FALLOUT' as "STATUS", coalesce(sum(response_count),0) as "COUNT" from f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-22 00:00:00','2015-08-05 01:00:00', null, 'LINK')
where wfc_result = 'TM_FAIL'
union
select 'WFC_PENDING' as "STATUS", coalesce(sum(response_count),0) as "COUNT" from f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-22 00:00:00','2015-08-05 01:00:00', null, 'LINK')
where wfc_result = 'PENDING';
```

Output:

```
Status       Count
Integrated     40
TM_FALLOUT      50
WFC_PENDING      60
WFC_FALLOUT      70
```

The output format above is what I need. But this query takes a lot of time.

The query that I want to use is the following as it takes less time.

```
select 
sum(CASE WHEN wfc_result IN ('TM_OK','TM_NO_CHANGE') THEN response_count ELSE 0 END) as "INTEGRATED", 
sum(CASE WHEN wfc_result LIKE 'WFC%' THEN response_count ELSE 0 END) as "WFC_FALLOUT",
sum(CASE WHEN wfc_result = 'TM_FAIL' THEN response_count ELSE 0 END) as "TM_FALLOUT",
sum(CASE WHEN wfc_result = 'PENDING' THEN response_count ELSE 0 END) as "WFC_PENDING"
from f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-22 00:00:00','2015-08-05 01:00:00',null, 'LINK')
```

However, the output of this query is as follows, I need the same output as I get from the first query.

```
Integrated   WFC_FALLOUT   TM_FALLOUT   WFC_PENDING
40             50            60              70
```

I tried several ways but unable to find out how I can edit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'wfc_result' `WFC%` is always `WFC_%` yo can do the following:

```
SELECT status.lbl AS status, coalesce(sum(response_count), 0) AS count
FROM (VALUES
  ('TM_O', 'INTEGRATED'),
  ('TM_N', 'INTEGRATED'),
  ('WFC_', 'WFC_FALLOUT'),
  ('TM_F', 'TM_FALLOUT'),
  ('PEND', 'WFC_PENDING')) status(cls, lbl)
LEFT JOIN f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-22 00:00:00', '2015-08-05 01:00:00', NULL, 'LINK') wfc
  ON substr(wfc.wfc_result, 1, 4) = status.cls
GROUP BY 1;
```

If there are only a few 'wfc_result' strings `LIKE 'WFC%'` you could also spell them out (as well as the other *classes*) in the `VALUES` clause and then drop the `substr()` function in the `JOIN` clause.

To get the total output, the query is much simpler:

```
SELECT sum(response_count) AS total_count
FROM f_wfc_transaction_summary_isocc_ft_sum_no_tid('2015-07-22 00:00:00', '2015-08-05 01:00:00', NULL, 'LINK');
```

This does of course make another call to the expensive function, but there is no way to get around that *on the database*; in your client application you could simply sum up the "count" values returned from the previous query.

Comment: This is great. What if I also want a TOTAL as output which totals the response count value of all rows?

Comment: You are welcome. See updated answer for total count.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. What if I want to combine the total country query with lets say, TM_O and TM_N counts.

Comment: While you can do that with a `UNION` (much like your initial solution presented in the question, add a dummy column for 'status' on the total country query), those are two different queries so you would want to solve that issue on the application side, not as a SQL query. Keep logically separate things separate.